# how dictionary in list to DataFrame in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list, but I want DataFrame type

```
list1 = [{'id': a, 'res' : {'one':1, 'two':2,'three':3}}, 
         {'id': b, 'res' : {'one':1, 'two':2,'four':3}}
        ]
```

result :

```
  id   one   two     three   four
  a    1      2       3       Na
  b    1      2       Na      3
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried so far?

Comment: sorry, my first question in stackoverflow. next time i try good question format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1 = [{'id': 'a', 'res' : {'one':1, 'two':2,'three':3}} , {'id': 'b', 'res' : {'one':1, 'two':2,'four':3}}]
mod = list()

for d in list1:
    data = dict()
    data['id'] = d['id']
    for k,v in d['res'].items():
        data[k] = v
    mod.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(mod)
```

This will do what you want

Comment: FWIW, `pd.DataFrame({'id': i['id'], **i['res']} for i in list1)`…